# ErrorBars/ other way of visualising deviation in Paired Bar Charts (PBC)

Tags: plotting, charts

Data:

- three categories A,B,C
- values in each category: 
  `{median-semiIQR, sIQR (such that this value = median), sIQR (such that this value = median + sIQR)}`

e.g. `{{90, 21, 21}, {57, 14, 14}, {117, 69, 69}}`

What I want:

Preferably, just bar indicating the median value, then an errorbar added, indicating the sIQR, but how is this done in a PBC?

Else: cat. A is Red, cat. B Blue and cat. C Green. The last two values of each category have to be Blended, so that they are Pinkish, Lightblueish and LightGreenish, to indicate that these are sIQRs.

In addition, I would like to display the median value for each category

Comment: ErrorBar or ErrorListPlot? Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"].

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/Files/AddErrorBarsToChartsAndPlots.en/O_5.gif. I'd like to have somthing like this, but the method mentioned there doesn't work with a PBC (that has its bars in the horizontal direction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial answer addressing the PBC part of the question...

Using a modification of the  function `errorBar` in OP's other question [(Spacing the elements in a bar chart with error bars)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61672/125) to make it work with `PairedBarChart`:

```
ClearAll[pbcErrorBar];
pbcErrorBar[type_: "GlassRectangle"][{{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}}, value_, meta_] :=
 Block[{error, z}, error = Flatten[meta];
  error = If[error === {}, 0, Last[error]]; z = If[x0 < 0, x0, x1];
  {ChartElementData[type][{{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}, value, meta],
   {Black, Line[{{{z - error, (y0 + y1)/2}, {z + error, (y0 + y1)/2}},
      {{z + error, 1/4 (3 y0 + y1)}, {z + error, 1/4 (y0 + 3 y1)}},
      {{z - error, 1/4 (3 y0 + y1)}, {z - error, 1/4 (y0 + 3 y1)}}}]}}];
```

and data similar to the one in the same Q/A:

```
cd = {RandomReal[1, 10], RandomReal[0.1, 10]};
chartData = Flatten@MapThread[{#1 -> #2} &, cd];
chartData2 = MapAt[# + RandomReal[] &, chartData, {{;; , 1}}];
```

we get

```
PairedBarChart[{chartData}, {chartData2},
 ChartElementFunction -> pbcErrorBar[],
 ChartStyle -> Rest@ColorData[3, "ColorList"], ImageSize -> 500,
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Segoe UI", FontSize -> 16},
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[Style[#, "Panel", 16] & /@ {"A", "B"}, Above],
                       None, Style[#, "Panel", 14] & /@ CharacterRange["a", "j"]}]
```

[image]