# How to add error bars to a stacked bar chart?

Tags: warning-messages, charts

Sorry, I know how to make error bars on normal bar charts, but how can I add vertical error bars to the top of my stacked bar charts, please?

```
BarChart[{{5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

Something that would look like this:

[image: Something that would look like this:]

I managed to cheat using `Show, but I'd prefer a more elegant method.

[image]

Comment: I am a bit biased about this but...You should free yourself from the desire to use stacked bar charts (especially ones with error bars).  Consider this:  https://peltiertech.com/stacked-bar-chart-alternatives/.

Comment: Thanks Jim, interesting link. I know stacked bar charts are imperfect, especially since the error bars I am adding are for the whole bar and not just the last rectangle, but that's the way information has been represented in the field where I am trying to publish a paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** In versions 12.0+, you can use [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html):

```
BarChart[{{5, Around[5, 6], 5}, {2, Around[2, 3], 4}}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use a slightly modified version of the function `errorBar` from  [howto/AddErrorBarsToChartsAndPlots](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/AddErrorBarsToChartsAndPlots.html) (see also [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61672/125)):

```
ClearAll[errorBar]
errorBar[type_: "Rectangle"]:= Module[{error = If[#3 === {}, 0, #3[[1]]], 
   x0 = #[[1, 1]], x1 = #[[1, 2]], y1 = #[[2, 2]]},   
 {ChartElementData[type][##],  {Black, 
  Line[{{{(x0 + x1) / 2, y1 - error}, {(x0+x1)/2 ,  y1  + error}}, 
   {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), y1 + error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1),  y1  + error}}, 
   {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), y1  - error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), y1  - error}}}]}}]&
```

and add the error information as metadata to the last element in each data group

```
BarChart[{{5, 5, 5 -> 7}, {2, 3, 4 -> 2}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartElementFunction -> {Automatic, Automatic, errorBar[]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** ***What if I want to put the error bar on the second rectangle out of the three?***

You can post-process the `BarChart` output to reorder groups of primitives so that the second rectangle (and the error lines associated with it)  is at the end:

```
bc = BarChart[{{5, 5 -> 6, 5}, {2, 3 -> 2, 4}}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartElementFunction -> {Automatic, errorBar[], Automatic}]; 
bc /. x : {{_Directive, __} ..} :> RotateLeft[x, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
    BarChart[{{5, 5 -> 6, 5},
  {2, 3 -> 3, 4}},
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ChartElementFunction -> {Automatic, errorBar[], Automatic}]

What if I want to put the error bar on the second rectangle out of the three. The last rectangle is in front of the error bar. Would you please know how to solve this without playing with the opacity of the last rectangle?

Comment: @Tommy95, my pleasure. A hack to put the error bar on the second rectangle : `bc = BarChart[{{5, 5 -> 6, 5}, {2, 3 -> 3, 4}}, 
   ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   ChartElementFunction -> {Automatic, errorBar[], Automatic}];
bc /. x : {{_Directive, __} ..} :> x[[{1, 3, 2}]]`